# MongoDB Filter Nested Array in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection in MongoDB that looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    "machine": 1,
    "status": true,
    "comments": [
      {
        "machine": 1,
        "status": false,
        "emp": "158",
        "comment": "testing the latest update"
      },
      {
        "machine": 1,
        "status": false,
        "emp": "007",
        "comment": "2nd comment"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "machine": 2,
    "status": true,
    "comments": [
      {
        "machine": 2,
        "status": true,
        "emp": "158",
        "comment": "checking dcm 2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I would like to return ALL of the top level documents (machines 1 & 2), but only comments by emp "007". I also only want to return the latest comment, not all. I got that part working with this line:

```
await db.collection('status').find().project( { "comments": { "$slice": -1 } }).toArray()
```

But I cannot for the life of me get it to then filter by 'emp' in the nested array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple aggregation with `$filter` to get a clean output:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      machine: 1,
      status: 1,
      comments: {
        $slice: [
          {
            $filter: {
              input: "$comments",
              as: "item",
              cond: {$eq: ["$$item.emp", "007"]}}
          }, -1
        ]
      },
      _id: 0
    }
  },
  {$set: {comments: {$arrayElemAt: ["$comments", 0]}}},
])
```

[Playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XaUAwxKnqUw)

Comment: This is a nice solution, but it is only giving me results where the employee in question (007) has commented. I would like the full ten machines. I also need the status from the top level, not the nested document.

Comment: Even easier. Please check the updated response

Comment: This is great and I'll mark it as the solution as it's all I've asked for in the original question. However, is there a way to return a comments array even when none matches? I can (and perhaps should) handle that in React, but I'd just like to have the option.

Comment: For anyone interested the way to handle this in React (as the json returned is an object), is to use `{status.comments ? status.comments.comment : null}` - assuming you're using a functional component.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "comments.machine": {
        $in: [
          1,
          2
        ]
      },
      "comments.emp": "007"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {//addFields with same name overwrites the array
      "comments": {
        "$filter": { //Filter the array elements based on condition
          "input": "$comments",
          "as": "comment",
          "cond": {
            $eq: [
              "$$comment.emp",
              "007"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IhjiybWREUI)

If you have a date, sort by that and get the top one.

Comment: Is "comments.emp": "007" working when this is inside an array? The playground works only part of the time...

Comment: You are correct, my bad. There could be multiple comments. Hence, corrected with my usual approach.

Comment: Appreciate the help, but again, this is not returning the machines that do not have a comment from that particular individual. I also want it to only the latest comment using something like the '$slice' parameter as above.

Comment: Why it should have machines that's not from that individual? You can remove 007 check in match stage, That will return for all the machines